# How to transpile node_modules modules with babel-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules, babeljs, babel-loader

**Problem:** I want to build bundle files for a website for older browsers (>= IE10).

My transpiled code throws errors on old Internet Explorer 11 when I transpile the code with `babel 7.x` using `babel-loader` as it seems `node_modules` modules won't get transpiled anymore by default?

**Question:** How can I make sure that all my `node_module` modules will be transpiled if they aren't transpiled by the package author already?

#### webpack.config.js using babel-loader

```
// webpack.config.js
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
        exclude: [],
    },
],
```

#### babelrc.js config using babel 7.x

```
// .babelrc.js
module.exports = function(api) {
    const presets = [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                ignoreBrowserslistConfig: true,
                targets: {
                    node: 8,
                    browsers: [
                        'last 3 versions',
                        '> 1% in DE',
                        'Explorer >= 10',
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-react',
    ];

    const plugins = [
        // ...
    ];

    return {
        presets,
        plugins,
    };
};
```

---

#### Update 1:

It was an issue with babel. My babel config was named `.babel.rc` and babel 7 default setting is to look for a config file named `babel.config.js`, see [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#configfile).

So after renaming the babel config file from ´.babel.rc´ to ´babel.config.js´ I could apply a solution in my ´webpack.config.js´ described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031#issuecomment-219040479) to transform untransformed ´node_modules´ packages with a solution like that:

```
// webpack.config.js
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
        // Exclude the untransformed packages from the exclude rule here
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(MY_MODULE|ANOTHER-ONE)\/).*/, 
    },
],
```

**Question:** It feels like workaround, but isn't there a more convenient way to handle such issues? I just pretend there will be more and more untransformed packages outside in the near future (following [this discussion](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3564#issuecomment-432551741)) and do we always have to manually put the package names for it in webpacks' `exclude` rule??

Comment: you can make sure not adding anything to `exclude: []` options.

Comment: @PlayMa256: You mean in the `webpack.config.js`? I already tried that but it doesn't change anything. Same for adding the `exclude: []` to the `.babelrc.js` config, no change.

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031

Comment: Okay, it was an issue with babel. My babel config was named ´.babel.rc` and somewhere in the game babel changed the default setting for looking for the babel config file to `babel.config.js`, see here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#configfile.

So after renaming the config file the `exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(MY_MODULE |ANOTHER-ONE)\/).*/,` solution works fine now.

Comment: Thank you!!! Specifically this page helped me https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading

Answer (score 6):

> Question: It feels like workaround, but isn't there a more convenient
> way to handle such issues? I just pretend there will be more and more
> untransformed packages outside in the near future (following this
> discussion) and do we always have to manually put the package names
> for it in webpacks' exclude rule??

You can use modules like `are-you-es5` to automatically create an exception list or test: https://www.npmjs.com/package/are-you-es5

Also things like `eslint-plugin-compat` could potentially warn you of issues if pointed at your `node_modules`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-compat

It's not perfect though. I think in production settings in general you should just be cognizant of the packages you add before adding them or have some automated tests that would catch browser errors if IE11 is critical for your project.

I know it is not always possible but I would strongly suggest pushing IE11 and below to some lower tier support. It is very difficult to still maintain IE11 and below while using modern JS.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was an old question but recently I spent quite some time to fix the same problem so I would like to share my experience too.

First, `exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(MY_MODULE|ANOTHER-ONE)\/).*/` only works for *nix but not window because window uses `/` for path, so a universal solution using regex would be `exclude: /node_modules(?!(\/|\\)MY_MODULE|ANOTHER-ONE)/`

Second, using negative lookahead regex does feel awkward and https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#some-files-in-my-node_modules-are-not-transpiled-for-ie-11 has a better way

```
exclude: {
      and: [/node_modules/], // Exclude libraries in node_modules ...
      not: [
        // Except for a few of them that needs to be transpiled for IE
        /unfetch/,
        /d3-array|d3-scale/,
        /@hapi[\\/]joi-date/,
      ]
    },
```